# How to find directive and invoke ng-click with protractor?

Tags: angularjs, testing, protractor

I should find the Directive tile-mini and invoke the function within ng-click. How can I do?

HTML:

```
<tile-mini data="tableTile" ng-click="addDenuncia()" id="add-denuncia-tile"></tile-mini>
```

spec.js:

```
it('Inserimento DU', function() {
  browser.get('/#/valoritalia/admin/denunce-uva/inserimentoDU/all');
  element(by.model('autodichiarazione.viticoltore')).sendKeys('erbaluna 034').sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER);
  element(by.css(".button-next")).click();
  element(by.directive("tile-mini")).click();
  browser.pause();
  expect(browser.getTitle()).toBe('Inserimento DU DIONISO');
});
```

I tried with:

```
element(by.id("add-complaint-tile")).click ();
element(by.css('[ng-click = "addDenuncia()"]')).click()
directive.element(by.<something>); // Failed: Object [object Object] has no method 'directive'
```

None of these works ..

#### EDIT 1

```
var elementToFind = by.id("add-denuncia-tile");
browser.wait(function() {
  return browser.isElementPresent(element(elementToFind));
}, 30000).then(function(isPresent){
  if(isPresent){
    element(elementToFind).click();
  }
});
```

The error:

```
1) Dioniso Test Case Inserimento DU
  Message:
    Failed: element not visible
      (Session info: chrome=45.0.2454.101)
      (Driver info: chromedriver=2.19.346063 (38b35413bd4a486d436a9749e090454bc9ff6708),platform=Mac OS X 10.11.0 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
    Command duration or timeout: 19 milliseconds
    Build info: version: '2.47.1', revision: '411b314', time: '2015-07-30 03:03:16'
    System info: host: 'YoBre-work.local', ip: '192.168.1.51', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.11', java.version: '1.8.0'
    Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
    Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, chrome={userDataDir=/var/folders/7s/f_15rz4d7_d7t6rl6yxkbsk80000gn/T/.org.chromium.Chromium.uHFDeg}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=45.0.2454.101, platform=MAC, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
    Session ID: 7e22695fbe8a4a29cda083576bf34439
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just try to click on the element and leave the rest to protractor to invoke the function on `ng-click`. Also, there is no `directive` object in protractor which can be used. So you can use css or other element locators to click on the element. Here's how -

```
element(by.id('add-denuncia-tile')).click(); //Notice the id of the element which is typo in your question
```

If its still not clicking then do make sure the element is loaded and is enabled before you click. You can wait for the element using `elementToBeClickable` in protractor -

```
var elem = element(by.css('[ng-click = "addDenuncia()"]'));
browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(elem), 10000).then(function(){
     elem.click();
});
```

Hope it helps

Comment: @YoBre Well i saw typo in your `by.id` usage. Did you try to wait until element appears and then clicking on it? Also is the element in view to be clicked on or do you need to scroll the page to click it?

Comment: You are right! It was a mistake to copy-paste the id of the component. I correct it immediately and insert also the new proof that unfortunately is not successful.

Comment: Is your element in view window to be clicked? or do you have to scroll page to the element to click it? Also increase your timeout if your element loads very slow because i see that you are getting timeout in 19ms.